# Достаю из базы или 1 изображение или 3, как различить?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Добрый день.

В общем имеется у меня база с пользователями, и на каждого пользователя есть либо 1, либо сразу 3 изображения, эти они сами решают сколько своих фотографий добавить.
И есть div, при клике на него вытягивается либо 1 изображение, либо сразу 3.
Если 1 - отображается в div'е как обычная картинка, если в базе у этого пользователя оказалось 3 картинки - отображаем их в том же div'е, но в слайдере (чтоб можно было листать влево/вправо).
Так вот вопросики:

Где лучше всего хранить эти изображении. Для каждого свое поле или, в случае если изображений больше одного - все в одной ячейке, но разделять их допустим " **|** " ?

Как определить сколько же у юзера там изображений, чтобы правильно 'раскидать изображения', чтобы знать нужно засовывать картинки в слайдер, или же вывести обычной картинкой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В базе это отдельная таблица с линками на юзеров.
А на фронтенде - это всегда слайдер, просто когда 1 изображение не отображаются стрелки.

Comment: т.е. в базе 2 таблицы, в 1 список юзеров, в другой все изображения. И присоединять изображения к соответствующим юзерам?

Comment: Именно так;)

Comment: спасибо за совет, но у меня тут и так слишком много фильтров при выборке, а еще и изображения добавлять.. выйдет накладно)  
реализовал через "|" в одной ячейке)

Comment: Дамс... Дело ваше, но это неверный ход;) перемотрите фильм "поворот не туда"

Comment: ))) чего ж не верный?))  
получая с базы строчку проверяем, есть ли в ней "|", если нету - значит картинка одна.  
если есть, разбиваем split'ом и распихиваем в массив. после чего скармливаем массив слайдеру.  
ведь всё ж хранится в одной ячейке и доставать вообще не трудно, никаких лишних движений в базе. манипуляций с изображениями мне никаких делать не нужно, просто листать влево и вправо

Comment: С этой точки зрения - верно, а с точки зрения расширяемости проекта - нет! 3 фотки - хрен с ними, а если возможно будет залить 10000 фоток...?;)

Comment: нет, в том то и дело)
у меня предел 3 изображения
минимум 1, максимум - 3

Comment: Сегодня так, а завтра иначе)) дело ваше)))